# PhP curl simple_dom_document request to get snow data from snowbird.com

Tags: php, html, curl, simple-html-dom

Im using php, curl, and simple_dom_document to get snow data from snowbird.com. The problem is I cant seem to actually find the data I need. I am able to find the parent div  and its name but I cant find the actually snow info div. Here is my code. Below my code ill past a small part of the output.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT     5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load($content);


$ret = $html->find('.horizSnowChartText');
$ret = serialize($ret);
$ret3 = new simple_html_dom();
$ret3->load($ret);
$es = $ret3->find('text');
$ret2 = $ret3->find('.total-inches');

print_r($ret2);
//print_r($es);
?>
```

And here is a picture of the output. You can see it skips the actual snow data and goes right to the inches mark ".
[image: outputcode]

Comment: if you already found it, a simple `echo` will do

Comment: You're just wanting the total inches? `echo $ret3->find('.total-inches')->innertext;`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you very much, I found out my problem was not using the ->innertext after my find like you showed in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that the html markup you're getting has multiple instances of `.total-inches` (multiple nodes with this class). If you want to explicitly get one, you can point to it directly using the second argument of `->find()`.

Example:

```
$ret2 = $html->find('.total-inches', 3);
                                   // ^
```

If you want to check them all out, a simple `foreach` should suffice:

```
foreach($html->find('.current-conditions .snowfall-total .total-inches') as $in) {
    echo $in , "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ghost. With yours and Ohgodwhys help I was able to make it work. You guys are a life saver